# rolling_sum on business day and return new dataframe with date as index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have such a `DataFrame`:

```
                     A
2016-01-01 00:00:00  0
2016-01-01 12:00:00  1

2016-01-02 00:00:00  2
2016-01-02 12:00:00  3
2016-01-03 00:00:00  4
2016-01-03 12:00:00  5

2016-01-04 00:00:00  6
2016-01-04 12:00:00  7
2016-01-05 00:00:00  8
2016-01-05 12:00:00  9
```

The reason I separate **2016-01-02 00:00:00** to **2016-01-03 12:00:00** is that, those two days are **weekends**.

---

So here is what I wish to do:

I wish to `rolling_sum` with `window = 2 business days`.

For example, I wish to sum

```
                     A
2016-01-04 00:00:00  6
2016-01-04 12:00:00  7
2016-01-05 00:00:00  8
2016-01-05 12:00:00  9
```

and then sum (we skip any non-business days)

```
                     A
2016-01-01 00:00:00  0
2016-01-01 12:00:00  1

2016-01-04 00:00:00  6
2016-01-04 12:00:00  7
```

And the result is

```
                     A
2016-01-01           Nan
2016-01-04           14
2016-01-05           30
```

---

How can I achieve that?

I tried `rolling_sum(df, window=2, freq=BDay(1))`, it seems it just pick one row of the same day, but not sum the two rows (00:00 and 12:00) within the same day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first select only business days, resample to (business) daily frequency for the remaining data points and sum, and then apply `rolling_sum`:

Starting with some sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': np.random.randint(0, 10, 500)}, index=pd.date_range(datetime(2016,1,1), freq='6H', periods=500))

                     A
2016-01-01 00:00:00  6
2016-01-01 06:00:00  9
2016-01-01 12:00:00  3
2016-01-01 18:00:00  9
2016-01-02 00:00:00  7
2016-01-02 06:00:00  5
2016-01-02 12:00:00  8
2016-01-02 18:00:00  6
2016-01-03 00:00:00  2
2016-01-03 06:00:00  0
2016-01-03 12:00:00  0
2016-01-03 18:00:00  0
2016-01-04 00:00:00  5
2016-01-04 06:00:00  4
2016-01-04 12:00:00  1
2016-01-04 18:00:00  4
2016-01-05 00:00:00  6
2016-01-05 06:00:00  9
2016-01-05 12:00:00  7
2016-01-05 18:00:00  2
....
```

First select the values on business days:

```
tsdays = df.index.values.astype('<M8[D]')
bdays = pd.bdate_range(tsdays[0], tsdays[-1]).values.astype('<M8[D]')
df = df[np.in1d(tsdays, bdays)]
```

Then apply `rolling_sum()` to the resampled data, where each value represents the sum for an individual business day:

```
pd.rolling_sum(df.resample('B', how='sum'), window=2)
```

to get:

```
             A
2016-01-01 NaN
2016-01-04  41
2016-01-05  38
2016-01-06  56
2016-01-07  52
2016-01-08  37
```

See also [here] for the type conversion and [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841487/pandas-number-of-business-days-between-two-dates)[this question][2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25597200/extract-business-days-in-time-series-using-python-pandas) for the business day extraction.